# Copy from cell range on 'sheet1' to same range on 'sheetB3'

Tags: vba, excel

I had a hard time formulating the title, but I'll explain better here.

What I want to do is use a VBA-macro that I'm activating from a button click to copy the data found in the range B13:E52 on sheet1 to the same range on sheet"B3", where B3 is found on sheet1 containing the sheet name I want to copy to. This dynamically updates depending on what item is chosen in a list.

I know how to create my button, copy between sheet etc but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to reference the target sheet name that's contained in B3 for the target in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to copy only the vlaues (without the formats or formulas), then you can use :

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Worksheets(.Range("B3").Value).Range("B13:E52").Value = .Range("B13:E52").Value
End With
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I call for a sub with this code

`With Worksheets("Indata")
        Worksheets(.Range("Z5").Value).Range("D13:F32").Value = .Range("D13:F32").Value
End With`

I've done it previously using 

`Worksheets("1").Range("D13:F32").Value = Worksheets("Indata").Range("D13:F32").Value`

Only that the worksheet named "1" is a different number based on a list choice, apparently I had it in Z5 and not B3 as previously mentioned. Wow it seems I cant properly format this comment. Sorry

Comment: @user1321795 actualy it works fine when I just tested it, do you have the sheet's name you want to paste to at cell "Z5" at sheet "Indata" ?

Comment: Yes, Ive edited my comment. didn't release it would post everytime I hit enter to try and make a new row

Comment: If it matters I'm fetching the sheet name I want to copy to using a match command

Comment: I got it working. I was under the impression that it would use the name of the sheet which was 1, not the order of my sheets and since the first sheet was hidden I never noticed!

Comment: @user1321795 glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
with sheet1
    .range("b13:e52").copy sheets(.range("b3").value).range("b13")
end with
```